# Create user interface like aptitude in python

Tags: python, user-interface

I want create a user interface in python such as ubuntu's aptitude, how can i create it ?! it work in command line, not GUI .
it has menubar, shortkey and colored .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Comment: You probably want [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module.

Comment: Just look at [PipUI](http://code.google.com/p/pipui/) and modify it if you don't like it?

Answer (score 2):

As stated, the question is really vague. 
There is a higher level library than the curses module available, [urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/).
The [tutorials](http://excess.org/urwid/docs/tutorial/) even go into setting up menus.

If you get stuck, post a question with any code you have, that makes it easier to help you.